# Unity Graphics.DrawMesh equivalent for Physics?

Tags: unity, physics, instancing

I'm working on something where the same graphics mesh is rendered multiple times in the scene. The problem with this is that each of those graphics items have a physics mesh which isn't there in the manually drawn meshes...

I've looks for something in the [Physics](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.html) and [Collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.html) documentation but haven't found anything which does what DrawMesh does for physics meshes. Is there something for this? or will I have to just create a bunch of physics objects manually?

Comment: Is there a reason to not use GameObjects for each mesh? Unity does do automatic batching when possible.

Comment: It does batch them but there are hundreds and I don't want to manage them. Placing them in the scene takes a while. They are identical copies of each other just in different locations so if I can get them to all trigger their behaviour in the same way then it saves me a bit of hassle making A duplicate an action in B, C, D, etc.

Comment: Is there a reason you can’t create the GameObjects from a prefab in the scene at runtime, just once in Start(), rather than draw them every frame in update? I don’t think there’s a way to do what you want to do that’s going to be simpler than having a bunch of GameObjects anyway.

Comment: Thats basically what I've ended up doing now but I'm not really happy about it because of all the syncing :(